# What is the difference of Implementing Serializable vs. Extending Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, jms

We are having some errors reading an object message off of a JMS queue. It seems like it is occuring during the object serialization.

I went into the domain library we are using and the root class of the object model is declared as "extends Serializable" instead of "implements Serializable"...

Are there any differences to the two approaches, I have typically only ever seen the "implements Serializable" variant. Could this have a side effect that is causing the problems we are seeing?

Answer (score 7):

`extends <interface>` is reserved for interfaces. Only an interface can extend from multiple interfaces. Classes (including abstract) will only implement interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Since [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is an interface, only another interface can *extend* it. All concrete classes that wish to use an interface must *implement* it.

Comment: So if I see JMS errors on subclasses that do not explicitly implement Serializable could it be caused by this quirk in the object hierarchy?

They also do not ever declare a unique serializable id...

Comment: @MichaelReynolds What quirk in the object hierarchy? If your classes aren't Serializable you will get errors if you try to Serialize them. If you tried to extend an interface in a class, you would get a compiler error.

Comment: It's an external library we have... say this: 

class A extends Serializable

Class B extends class A

We are putting class B onto our JMS queue.

Comment: @MichaelReynolds `class A extends Serializable` would get a compiler error.

Comment: This is the HAPI library for HL7 data, i am in the source right now and there is a nested object structure but this is how the root interface that the object inherits from:

public interface Structure extends Serializable

Comment: @MichaelReynolds Yes. That's an `interface`. Not a `class`. Anything that implements `Structure` is also `Serializable`.